# error del tipo de tipo de parámetro MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Alguien sabe por qué sale el siguiente error?

> The type parameter 'VerificadorWeb.Datos.p_vw_consulta_precio_producto_Result' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'VISION_WEBModel.p_vw_consulta_precio_producto_Result' returned by the function.
>   `new ObjectParameter("location_id", typeof(int));`
>   `return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<p_vw_consulta_precio_producto_Result>("p_vw_consulta_precio_producto", barcodeParameter, location_idParameter);`

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Ismael, bienvenido a SOes. Te invito a que puedas [edit] tu pregunta para incluir cual es el objetivo de tu código y que estas intentando hacer, y no poner solo el mensaje de error, porque es muy dificil entender que esta pasando. Puedes ver este enlace para ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Saludos.

Comment: no entiendo que necesitas.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a SOes! Te invito a dar una vuelta por el https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio con un mayor detalle, por otro lado, ¿Podrías al menos colocar lo que está haciendo (el querystring, la consulta que le haces al webservice, los parámetros que envías) por favor ?